# Random position for ImageView and animation

Tags: android

My application is simple: Some ImageViews are created randomly outside the layout then they will move straight forward into the layout and disappear when they reach the other side. The idea is simple but I can't make it happen. Please help me!

Comment: Is it some animation stuff you are talking about? Can you edit the question to make it clear and add the code that you have tried?

Comment: Please elaborate further and add your code.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
TranslateAnimation tA=new TranslateAnimation(randomX,randomY,endX,endY);
image.setAnimation(tA);
tA.start();
```

Comment: what is endX and endY

Comment: If it is the end coordinates of the phone, how do I find that programmatically?